# Add constraint on the values allowed for a property with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

With EntityFramework Core how can I limit a property to some values with the modelBuilder ?

In SQL it's :

```
CONSTRAINT chk_Frequency CHECK (Frequency IN ('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Yearly'))
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can use an enum

```
public enum Frequency
{
    Daily,
    Weekly,
    Monthly,
    Yearly
}
```

Then use EF Core value conversion with the EnumToStringConverter. This will work:

```
modelBuilder
   .Entity<Rider>()
   .Property(e => e.Mount)
   .HasConversion<string>();
```

It will not create the constraint in the database but it will put the enum type on the mapped property. If a bad value comes from the database it will map to the enum's default value.

Comment: "it will not create the constraints" which is weird... 5.0.0-prerelease, for me, it did... but in 5.0.1 it's removing the constraints. Trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> str = new List<string>(){"Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Yearly'}
```

in entity framework use Where

```
.Where(x=> str.Contains(x.Frequency ))
```